# cannot make a call using action.call after register of broadcast receiver for phone state

Tags: android

On Button Click i could make a call using Intent -> Action Call. Later in the code i implemented Broadcast Received. I found that once BroadcasteReceiver is registered Calls using Intent->action.Call is not process. Kindly help.

// This function is called on button click

```
fun callPerson(position: Int) {
    val callObject = allCallList?.get(position)
    try {
        var startIndent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        startIndent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + callObject?.number)
        ContextCompat.startActivity(mContext as Context, startIndent, null)
    }

    catch(ex : Exception) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext,Toast.message.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } 
}
```

//Permission taken

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


//Service 
class CallCaptureService : Service()
{
    private var callCapture = CallCapture()
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        var intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");

        intentFilter?.priority = 100
        registerReceiver(callCapture, intentFilter)

    }
```

override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(callCapture)
    }

}

//CallCapture is receiver

```
 class CallCapture : BroadcastReceiver(){

       override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
            if (intent?.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                Staticated.savedNumber = intent?.getExtras()?.getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER")

            } else {
                val stateStr = intent?.getExtras()?.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                val number = intent?.getExtras()?.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                var state = 0
                if (stateStr == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
                } else if (stateStr == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                } else if (stateStr == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
                }

                onCallStateChanged(context, state, number)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked runtime permission for it if your target version is _>=24_ ?

Comment: yes. in my Splash screen i take permissions ->              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS ), requestReadLog)

Comment: So are you sure your call is not working and you'r getting toast in exception?

Comment: yes..first it worked...then i added the broadcast receiver . i register the receiver in the mainactivity as service.

Comment: Why do you need receiver? For what purpose?

Comment: i am maintaining my own DB in SQLLite.

Comment: But what is related to it? You need to mention in detail

Comment: The app copy data from CallLog to DB then everytime a call is made or recevied the DB gets updated. i dont have to refer to the CallLog. I have my own customised features for the list received

Comment: Any Pointers Please Help

Comment: I want to see broadcast receiver

Comment: No Pointers Still... i need it urgently

Comment: DM me mail......